# How to get data from all the text fields in a single variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a screen `IndividualDetails.js` that renders a component called `IndividualInfoCard` in a for loop:

```
let indCards = [];
for (let index = 0; index < totalIndividuals; index++) {
  indCards.push(<IndividualInfoCard noOfInd={index + 1} key={index} />);
}
```

The `IndividualInfoCard` component is:

```
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [passportNRIC, setPassportNRIC] = useState('')
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('')
    const [dob, setDOB] = useState('')

    var noOfIndSelected = noOfInd;

    const individualDetails = {
        fullName: name,
        email: email,
        phone: phoneNumber,
        passportNRIC: passportNRIC,
        dob: dob
    }

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>Individual {noOfIndSelected}</Text>
            <TextInput placeholder={'Enter Full Name *'} value={name} onChangeText={setName} style={styles.textField} editable={true} />
            <TextInput placeholder={'Enter Email *'} value={email} onChangeText={setEmail} style={styles.textField} editable={true} />
            <TextInput placeholder={'Enter Passport or NRIC Number *'} value={passportNRIC} onChangeText={setPassportNRIC} style={styles.textField} editable={true} />
            <TextInput placeholder={'Phone Number *'} value={phoneNumber} onChangeText={setPhoneNumber} style={styles.textField} editable={true} />
            <TextInput placeholder={'Date of Birth *'} value={dob} onChangeText={setDOB} style={styles.textField} editable={true} />
  </View>
);
```

If let's say the individuals are three there will be three `IndividualInfoCard` components on the screen.

Now on the screen `IndividualDetails.js` I need to get all of this data from the three cards in say an array `[{ind: 1, fullname: 'Person'...}]`

To do that I've a button on this screen in which I've user a `forEach` loop like this:

```
<MainActionButton title={'Continue'} pressEvent={() => {
    indCards.forEach(indiv => {
       alert(HOW_TO_GET_SAY_EMAIL_HERE)
    });
}} />
```

Comment: use Forms library to handle the form in React. Formik or React-final-form

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it with useState

do this:

```js
import {useState} from 'react'

const [name, setName] = useState('')
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('')
// other inputs if you want more

const individualDetails = {
    fullName: name,
    email,
    phoneNumber,
    // and the other inputs if you want
}

return (
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Individual {noOfIndSelected}</Text>
        <TextInput placeholder="Enter Full Name" value={name} onChangeText={setName} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Enter Email" value={email} onChangeText={setEmail} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Enter Phone Number" value={phoneNumber} onChangeText={setPhoneNumber} />
    </View>
)
```

The individualDetails const is what you want, use this code in any screen you want.

also to prevent using a lot of states, you can use formik.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've implemented the way you are describing but just one this left to figure out and I've updated the code in my question. Now in the class where all the three small form components are I've marked `HOW_TO_GET_SAY_EMAIL_HERE` so if I'm able to get that info there it'll be all. So how do I call the `individualDetails` over there?

Comment: type export before const individualDetails:

export const individualDetails     and in other page: import {individualDetails} from '(the page that individualDetails is in it)'